# Cloning/serialization produces wrong class because of different dlls

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

I have a dll library TaskLibrary.dll with a class `Execution` performing some `Operation`(s) and a class `ParallelizeExecution` that takes a single `Execution`, clones it and executes the `Run` method of the multiple `Execution` instances.

The `Clone` method of the `Execution` class works by converting the `Execution` in xml and reverting it back to normal as a new instance

```
public Execution{
    List<AOperation> operations;

    public Run(){
        foreach(var op in operations){
            //...do stuff...
        }
    }

    public Execution Clone(){
        MyXmlSerializer.DeserializeObject<Execution>(
                MyXmlSerializer.SerializeObject(this));
    }
}

public ParallelizeExecution{
    List<Execution> toRun;
    public RunParallel(Execution e,int numExecutions){
        toRun=new List<Execution>();

        for(var i=0;i<numExecutions;i++){
            toRun.Add(e.Clone());
        }
    }
}
```

The `Execution` class is serializable as is each of the classes implementing `Operation`. This is obtained by using an abstract class (`AOperation`) which all the `IOperation` implementations extend, using the `XmlInclude` annotation to make `MyXmlSerializer` work for each `IOperation`.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Operation1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Operation2))]
public abstract class AOperation:IOperation{
    ...
}
```

Now I have a new project referencing the TaskLibrary.dll. I need to add a new kind of Operation to a `Execution`:

```
public class Operation3: Operation2 {
}
```

Everything works fine with a single execution, but when I use `ParallelizeExecution`  `Operation3` is correctly serialized as `Operation2` thus executing an unwanted `Run` method. How can I add a new type of `AOperation` to the `Execution` class and expect it to be correctly serialized and run in the `Execution`?

**OR**

How can I avoid the problem without altering the way the `Execution` class is serialized?

**Caveat**: I know that it is possible to use Reflection to xmlserialize any tipe extending a given one, but i'd rather learn how to do this using standard OOP (if possible).

**EDIT:** I could modify TaskLibrary.dll but I'd rather avoid this approach, it would void my efforts in learning new things and aiding the community, moreover it would be quite painful to redistribute the library to those already using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extraTypes argument to the [XmlSerializer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx).  Use reflection to find all of the relevant types, and create the XmlSerializer with the complete list.  The overall process is laid out [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/51437/Get-rid-of-XmlInclude-when-using-XmlSerializer), but for posterity's sake:

```
// use reflection to get all derived types
List<type> knownTypes = new List<type>();

// Iterate over whichever assembly has your types.
foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    if (typeof(Car).IsAssignableFrom(t) || 
        typeof(Wheel).IsAssignableFrom(t) ||
        typeof(Door).IsAssignableFrom(t))
       knownTypes.Add(t);

// prepare to serialize a car object
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car), knownTypes.ToArray());
```

Comment: I have a class that does the xml serialization, it is used in the ParallelizeExecution class, this solution forces me to edit the TaskLibrary.dll and I don't want/can't

Comment: The fact that you are using the `XmlSerializer` attributes like (`XmlInclude`) suggests to me that your custom class wraps XmlSerializer.  If that's the case, I'd look into modifying that class to instanciate XmlSerializer as I suggest above- that would allow you to add classes without modifying TaskLibrary.dll.  Otherwise I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Indeed I have a custom xml serializer, but it is inside TaskLibrary.dll

Comment: So you really don't use the built-in XmlSerializer at all?  You use one that is entirely custom, but that takes advantage of the built-in attributes?  In that case there is probably nothing that we can do to help you- you are in uncharted territory, because no one here knows how your serializer works.

Comment: Forgive me, I use a custom xml serializer that in turn wraps functionalities of the built-in XmlSerializer. The problem is: this "wrapper" is inside the dll that I'd rather not change. I'm looking for a workaround, for example making the "clone" method create the right type of object, but I have had no luck with this approach.

Comment: In the end I'll mark this answer as correct, for the purpose of the question it is, and try to create a new, more specific question. Thanks for your answer